# How to convert a string from one pattern to another using regex?

Tags: java, regex, converters

I have a string I want to convert using regex:

`AA_BB_CC_DD` => `EE_BB_FF_DD`

Tried using regex like `(AA)(.*)(FF)`. But that did not work. can someone help?

Also it would be nice if you can point me to a good regex guide. There are too many sites for regex. not sure which to refer.

Comment: For you second question, here's a nice [cheat sheet](http://i.imgur.com/BoK7Q3Q.png) for regex.

Comment: Which language are you using to execute your regex? There are different families of regex, so it's important to know which one to use.

Comment: Your regex says to match AA, followed by the letters ABC, followed by the letters FF.  How would the pattern 'AAABCFF' ever match the string AA_BB_CC_DD?

Comment: On what basis that you replace AA with EE, and CC with FF? It is not possible to do this without support for arbitrary replacement function.

Comment: Visibone make a great cheat sheet: http://www.visibone.com/regular-expressions/ -- if you're learning they sell them laminated and they're great to have as a physical reference that you can hold and stare at.

Comment: @7stud, I edited my post. But in any case I know my regex is wrong. can you help me write the correct one?

Comment: Sure.  What language are you using?  In perl, you would do this:

Comment: I am trying to use java

Comment: with (?:AA) I was able to match AA and replace it with EE. But my problem is to match both AA and CC and replace them with EE and FF respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
String before = "AA_BB_CC_DD";
String after = before.replaceFirst("AA(_BB_)CC(_DD)", "EE$1FF$2");

System.out.println(after);
// EE_BB_FF_DD
```

You haven't described how the form of the input string my vary, so it is difficult to produce a suitable regex.

If you wanted to allow almost anything between the `AA` and `CC` you could use `(.*?)` instead of `(_BB_)` etc.

The above shows the principle of using in the replacement string the content that is captured by the `()` , i.e. `$1` refers to the content in the first `()`, and `$2` the second `()`.

Links:
[Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).
[The Java Tutorials. Lesson: Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html).

Comment: Why not `String after = "EE_BB_FF_DD";` directly then? :)

Comment: @sp00m. The question states _"using regex"_ ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want complete explanations you can have a look here :
http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html

When you understand how it works the [Pattern API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is enough.

For your example, I suppose that AA -> EE, BB -> BB, CC -> FF, DD -> DD
So you can try the following :

```
String before = "AA_BB_CC_DD";
String after = before.replaceAll("AA_(.*)_CC_(.*)", "EE_$1_FF_$2");
```

And you get the result. I explain the regex :
"AA_(.*)*CC*(.*)"
The program try to match AA_, . means any character and * means repeat it. Thus any string between AA_ and *CC* is matched. The () indicate a group which is "memorized".

"EE_$1_FF_$2"
AA_ is replaced with EE_. $1 means print the first group ().
Same for FF and $2.

Comment: won't .* match everything until the end? `[^_]*` may be what you want.

Comment: Good remark from the example I suppose that DD was the end and since it remains the same.